# Remove spaces from before and after a string inside a tag in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim, spaces

I am trying to remove the spaces before and after string in a bold tag.

**Functionalities:**
I have created a text editor in which when u type a text and select the text and press bold it will bold the text and when you press html button, it shows the html generated in the next window.

**Issues faced:**
When i try to give tab space and then enter a text, and select the text along with the space and bold it, it bolds along with the empty space. Hence when i view the html in the html window i am able to see the space in the starting of the string.
The code i used removes all spaces from the string , but i just want to trim the starting and beginning and still keep the spaces in between the string just like that. Any help will be much appreciated.

**E.g:** when u try to bold a string along with the space **`'    fdgfg gfdgfg fdgfg'`** , this is how it looks in the editor .
The html generated looked like `<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;fdgfg gfdgfg fdgfg</b>`
So i wrote a code which removes those space, but it removes all spaces and am left with `<b>fdgfggfdgfgfdgfg</b>`. but what i actually want is `<b>fdgfg gfdgfg fdgfg</b>` without spaces.

**Script:**

```
//shows the html
  $("#show-html").click(function(){      
    var html = $("#textEditor").html();      
    html = html.replace(/&nbsp;|\s/gi, '');
  });
```

**[DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/75fbthww/2/)**

**P.S:** It should delete only the starting and the ending white spaces, it should preserve the spaces in between the text. e.g `"  abcd     efgh   "` this should be trimmed to `"abcd     efgh"` the spaces in between text should not be removed.

Comment: _"E.g: when u try to bold a string along with the space '    fdgfg gfdgfg fdgfg' , this is how it looks in the editor ."_ Why would `&nbsp;&nbsp;` be removed from `<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;fdgfg gfdgfg fdgfg</b>` if tab is highlighted and "HTML" button clicked ?

Comment: @guest271314  i am trying to view the html generated in another div, when i do that i am able to see the &nbsp; in the starting and ending of the string inside the bold tag. , i want to remove that .if u see the demo u wud understand what i am actually trying to do.

Comment: Yes , though `&nbsp;` would be part of the `html` entered , selected at editor ? Requirement does not include 1:1 representation of input at editor : `html` rendered at display window ?

Comment: yes ,i am just trying to show the user html tags generated in an uderstandable way . i don't want them to see those &nbsp; or spaces generated in the starting and ending of the tags.

Comment: Should `&nbsp` , space characters remain between tags ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95756/discussion-between-pbk1303-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to iterate over each of the `<b>` elements, remove all the consecutive whitespace, and then trim the string.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xsbp4wqx/)

```
$('#textEditor b').each(function () {
  $(this).text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
  });
});
```

Simple input:

```
"     this     is   a  string  "
```

Output:

```
<b>this is a string</b>
```

Comment: Croxier: this removes extra spaces in between the text also, i want to remove only the starting and ending. see my post script examples to understand better

Answer (score 1):

you can try `.trim()`

```
 str = "     something Here  ";
    console.log (str.trim());
```

or use it like this

```
$.trim(str);
```

Comment: will this work with the HTML generated code as well? (i.e. all the `&nbsp;`s in the input string)

Comment: @ochi don't use it after generate html .. use it before that .. when you catch the text from textarea when you click on bold button .. It should trim string before convert it to html